# Macbook Security Alarm Task

Tags: java

I intend to put my macbook on my landing/hallway for when the people downstairs come up to rummage through my bedroom/rooms, such that when an intruder is detected a set of scripted events occur, such as a countdown from 10 followed by very loud music, but the existing software is either commercial or insufficient. Im not intending to spend money on this.

Given a Macbook or desktop with a webcam. and using java, what libraries would I need to implement a basic version of the above? Also what references for implementing these kinds of motion detection programs would be useful?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what exactly you're looking for?

Comment: edited question to be clearer

Comment: Wouldn't this security scheme of yours just serve to notify any intruders that the room they are intruding/robbing has a Macbook in it that they could steal also?

Comment: no because the intruder lives downstairs and has a habit of going upstairs while Im in work and looking at my stuff. The aim here is to teach them a lesson by terrifying them with loud noise or some other annoying thing, or at least to tell me in work whats happening

Comment: What about locking the door to your room? :)

Comment: Theres no lock on some of the door, and she has all the keys

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/).

It is for C++ though, I am not sure if there is a version for Java.

It is the best API to handle webcams. If you can switch to C++ to use it then I would strongly suggest you do that.